# Online Data Collection

Tags: r, web-scraping, data-collection

I am attempting to collect data from 75,000 articles on web of knowledge. All the data could be viewed on each article's webpage. Being an absolute beginner in programming, I am unsure how this could be done other than manually. Is there any codes I could use on R or any other platforms to extract data from the webpages directly without having to download all of the articles?

Answer (score 1):

`rvest` is one really good R package for scraping general web data. It can so almost everything what python libraries `Beautiful Soup` or `Scrapy` do.

`XML` is another package that you can use for web scraping.

For scraping Twitter, you can use `twitteR` package and for Facebook `Rfacebook` package.

Use `RTidyHTML` package for correcting errors in HTML.